# Does DBCC ShrinkDatabase slow down sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a service which has been scheduled to run several times in a day. The service will execute a select query each time it fires.

It runs perfectly for sometimes but eventually it will hit the "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding." exception after sometime. This happens very randomly.

I run a trace in the sql profiler and see DBCC shrinkdatabase started around the time and used quite a lot of time but it is for another database on the same server.

I wonder if the shrinkdatabase action will slow down the sql server and is it possible for it to cause my query timeout?

Comment: WHy are you shrinking a database? Don't!

Comment: I didn't but my colleague did.

Comment: Stop doing it at once!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer would be yes but there are a lot of different things happening on the machine when you run the shrink database command which would all contribute towards slow queries.

1. There would be high Disk I/O when the data in the files are being re-arranged
2. Since the data has been re-arranged you would most likely have fragmentation on the indexes which could slow down your queries.
3. The operation is also very CPU intensive

You can get a lot of information on the shrink process on this page http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/shrinking-data-files